# How to get the version 2 linkdein api scopes?

Tags: api, migration, linkedin-api, scopes

I have made a linkedin extension for a business collaboration tool last year.Now I came to know that new version of linkedin api has been released.My extension is only using the basic scopes which are given default in the app creation page.I also noticed those scopes are still there at the app creation page and no new scopes are added.So will my extension still work with these basic scopes and code still.I tried to change them but I could see only those basic scopes in app page.If I mention new scopes in authentication request I am getting an error your app is not authenticated with this scope.So please someone clarify me how long will I am be able to use these basic scopes without migrating to version 2.Will version 1 api remain in use (even though not maintained) ?If I have to migrate how can I configure new scopes? If I try to create an app in linkedin developer,I am given only the basic scopes list that are in version 1 and new scopes added like the changed scope for share api is not showing up.If I try to add it directly on authentication request it is giving error response.Any help?

Note : I have used only the basic api scopes that doesn't require linkdein partnership program application.

I tried checking if I create a new app the version 2 scopes being listed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check this : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Basic is :
r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile)
r_emailaddress
w_member_social (replaces w_share)

you can use V1 scope till : March 1, 2019